# Microsoft Graph with Contains $filter for managedDevices

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble implementing a Microsoft Graph query for deviceMangement/managedDevices using multiple Contains $filters. All documentation points to this being possible, yet I'm not able to return any results when using Boolean "OR". It always seems to function as if I'm using Boolean "AND".

For example, let's say we have a Managed Device where deviceName is "computer-desktop" and the userPincipalName is "someone@example.com".

**The query below should return a device named "desktop-computer", but it returns nothing:**

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$filter=contains(deviceName, 'desktop-computer') or contains(userPrincipalName, 'desktop-computer')

**The query below should return a device where the UPN is "someone@example.com", but it returns nothing:**

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$filter=contains(deviceName, 'someone@example.com') or contains(userPrincipalName, 'someone@example.com')

**However, this query works just fine:**

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$filter=contains(deviceName, 'desktop-computer') or contains(userPrincipalName, 'someone@example.com')

This leads me to believe that Microsoft's supporting documentation is incomplete (surprise) or I've found a bug. I've tried this in two tenants but I'm hoping someone else can confirm I'm not crazy or maybe there's a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: I had the same [question](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues/1460) in the official Graph doc but the [answer](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues/1460#issuecomment-1679004683) was let's say strange

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The strange thing is $filter somewhat works, but its implementation appears to be janky when using OR. :(